# Call variable value through class or id using jQuery in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried `<span id="count"><?php echo $countofalsoin ; ?>`

```
<script language='javascript'>
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = <?php echo $countofalsoin; ?>;</script>
```

but is is printing value just below where I need to display i.e. in `class="listSimilarNews"`

I am making a counting format where my html code is written above my variable `$countofalsoin` in `for loop` I have tried a lot to call value by jQuery method call by class or id but not succeed, I think there is any better way to **call the variable value of `for loop` after whole page is rendered**.

cannot write html after getting value because of design purpose.

```
<?php
        
$IssuesCount =0;
$ArticleCount = 0; 
        
for($i=0; $i < count($row); $i++){
    $ArticleCount++;
    $title =$row[$i]['title'];
    $id = (string) $row[$i]['_id']; 
        
    ?>
        
    <div class="news-card NewsList">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ">
    <div class="news-left pb-0">
    <div class="view-more"><a data-toggle="collapse" class="listSimilarNews" href="#collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="#collapse">
        
        
    <!-- here is my html Where I am trying to echo $countofalsoin with some class or id with help of jQuery -->

    <span><?php echo $countofalsoin; ?></span><br>Articles</a></div>
    </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 news-content"> 
    <span class="heading">
    <?php
    echo htmlentities($title);
        
    ?>
    </span> 
    <?php 
        
    $j= $i+1; 
    ?>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapse<?=$i?>" style="" aria-expanded="true">
    <div class="card card-body">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #f5f5f5;">
    <div class="sub-news">
    <ul class="list-unstyled SimilarArticlesBind">
        
    <?php
    $countofalsoin = 0; 
    while(($j) < count($row) && ($id == (string) $row[$j]['_id'])){
        
        $countofalsoin ++;
        $IssuesCount++;
        
        ?>
        <li> 
        <?php echo ($row[$j]['newsSources']['link'])?>
        </li>
        <?php
        
        $i++;
        $j++;
    } 
        
    //here is my Value printing inside for loop 
        
    print_r($countofalsoin);
        
    ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        
        
    <?php
} 
?>
```

In the above code you can see below **`class="listSimilarNews"`** is my variable `$countofalsoin` which I am calling and slightly below **after while loop ends** I am **getting value of `$countofalsoin`,** is there any method to call it's value above **by jQuery** ? or any better suggestion !.

I cannot write html below because of design restrictions

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, there is no JS in your snippet.

Comment: Hi sir, how can I print my value by nearest class of `<div>` ?

Comment: Something like `$(this).find("span").text()`?

Comment: yes I have very basic knowledge in jQuery here I am trying to display my `$countofalsoin` through jQuery in html, any help is really really appreciated.

Comment: updated  @Barmar

Comment: There are multiple `$countofalsoin` values in the loop. Which one is supposed to go into the `count` DIV?

Comment: Why do you have `<span><?php echo $countofalsoin; ?></span>` before the `while` loop that sets `$countofalsoin`?

Comment: yes exactly multiple values of  `$countofalsoin` because of design issues  some values need to print before and after